# Convert JSON array to Class object

Tags: json, vb.net

I have the JSON below and I am attempting to convert it to the class `Utilities`.

I have added the class `Root` to facilitate the conversation of the JSON array to a list of the Utilities class.  I am getting an obj returned from each of the methods I have tried but the fields are all empty. What is the correct approach?

The JSON is contained in entries(0).

> [{"jobid":"BKTD3G4YOY","planned":"2018-10-16T16:07:28.9963532+00:00","routedate":"2018-10-16T17:07:28.0000000+01:00","estimated":"2018-10-16T17:07:28.0000000+01:00","notification":true,"ID":"3eb41e22-9f68-457e-851b-a97b00e98f6d","loss":23,"breakTimeLoss":0,"information":"Tour Create/Update"},{"jobid":"KP8W1XJVZ8","planned":"2018-10-16T18:07:28.9963532+00:00","routedate":"2018-10-16T19:48:45.0000000+01:00","estimated":"2018-10-16T19:48:45.0000000+01:00","notification":true,"ID":"3eb41e22-9f68-457e-851b-a97b00e98f6d","loss":23,"breakTimeLoss":0,"information":"Tour Create/Update"}]

```
<DataContract()> 
Public Class Utilities
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property jobid As String
        Get
            Return m_scmid
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_scmid = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_scmid As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property planned As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_planned
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_planned = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_planned As DateTime
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property routedate As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_routedate
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_routedate = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_routedate As DateTime
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property estimated As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_estmated
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_estmated = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_estmated As DateTime
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property notification As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_notification
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_notification = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_notification As Boolean
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ID As String
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ID As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property source As source
        Get
            Return m_source
        End Get
        Set(value As source)
            m_source = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_source As source
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property loss As Integer
        Get
            Return m_loss
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_loss = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_loss As Integer
    Private m_breakTimeLoss As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property information As String
        Get
            Return m_information
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_information = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_information As String 
End Class 

<DataContract()> 
Public Class source
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property timeStamp As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_timeStamp
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_timeStamp = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_timeStamp As DateTime
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property direction As Integer
        Get
            Return m_direction
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_direction = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_direction As Integer 
End Class 

<DataContract()> 
Public Class Root
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property entry As List(Of Utilities)
        Get
            Return m_entry
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Utilities))
            m_entry = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_entry As List(Of Utilities) 
End Class
```

The first method attempted:

```
 Dim serializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(List(Of Root)))
 Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(entries(0)))
 Dim obj As List(Of Root) = CType(serializer.ReadObject(ms), List(Of Root))
```

And the second method attempted:

```
 Dim account As List(Of Root) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Root))(entries(0))
```

Thanks for your replies, after posting this question yesterday I managed to get my code working. I did though have to add settings to handle the offset dates within the json!

```
Dim jsonSerializerSettings = New JsonSerializerSettings
                jsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
                jsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
                jsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind

                Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Root)(entries(0), jsonSerializerSettings)
```

Comment: Looks right. Seems like `entries(0)` may be the issue. Have you debugged and verified the actual content of entries(0) at runtime?  Also, try putting breakpoints in the setters and see if they get hit during deserialization.

Comment: Hi yes the only thing that I can think might be causing an issue is that some of the dates are offset values as '2018-10-16T19:48:45.0000000+01:00'  should I change the class members to reflect this?

Comment: Changged the DateTime's to DateTimeOffset but the data still failed to load!

Answer (score 0):

The `Root` class you have added is causing the problem here because the array items in your JSON do not have this extra layer (there is no property called `entry` in them).  You actually do not need this wrapper class at all.  You should just deserialize directly into a `List(Of Utilities)`.

```
Dim list As List(Of Utilities) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Utilities))(entries(0))
```

As an aside, you can simplify your `Utilities` class by using [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties).  This will save you from having to declare backing fields and write `Get` and `Set` methods for each property.  Also, if you are going to be using Json.Net instead of the `DataContractJsonSerializer` then you don't really need the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes here.  Json.Net will honor them, however.

One other thing: I noticed that your class was missing a public property for `breakTimeLoss`, which is present in the JSON, so you will need to add that if you want to capture that value.  Conversely, your class has a `Source` property for which there is no corresponding information in the JSON.  This is OK--it won't cause errors or anything--but just wanted to mention that it seems to be unnecessary.

With all these changes, the class declaration would look like this:

```
Public Class Utilities
    Public Property jobid As String
    Public Property planned As DateTime
    Public Property routedate As DateTime
    Public Property estimated As DateTime
    Public Property notification As Boolean
    Public Property ID as String
    Public Property loss As Integer
    Public Property breakTimeLoss As Integer
    Public Property information As String
End Class
```

Working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfSsts

Comment: Thanks for your replies, after posting this question yesterday I managed to get my code working. I did though have to add settings to handle the offset dates within the json!

Answer (score 0):

Hi below is a heirarchy of your class.

```
   Public Class Utilities

        <JsonProperty("jobid")>
        Public Property Jobid As String

        <JsonProperty("planned")>
        Public Property Planned As DateTime

        <JsonProperty("routedate")>
        Public Property Routedate As DateTime

        <JsonProperty("estimated")>
        Public Property Estimated As DateTime

        <JsonProperty("notification")>
        Public Property Notification As Boolean

        <JsonProperty("ID")>
        Public Property ID As String

        <JsonProperty("loss")>
        Public Property Loss As Integer

        <JsonProperty("breakTimeLoss")>
        Public Property BreakTimeLoss As Integer

        <JsonProperty("information")>
        Public Property Information As String
   End Class
```